# Upload Image through Jquery Modal

Tags: jquery-plugins

i want to upload photo to my application(asp.net mvc) using jquery Modal.

first i have created the div that will be displayed in the modal like the following :

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Upload File">
    <p>
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />

     </p>
</div>
```

then when i press some Hyberlink  the modal will appears and when i press ok 
i want to carry the photo to the action in controller for some processing ...

i dont know how to carry my photo to the server ...

the modal code looks like the following :

```
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            height: 200,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Ok: function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",

                        url: '<%: Url.Action("Upload", "SomeController") %>',
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.Success == true) {
                                alert(result.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

should i use the data in the $.ajax() .. but how ? 
and my controller expect from me nothing in signature...
public JsonResult Upload() just like this

it looks for the uploaded files in Request.Files
like :

foreach (string inputTagName in Request.Files)
{
some processing
}

any help please ??

Comment: Note : i have tried to add submit button to my div and include the hole div inside form and tried to submit the file by specifying the action attribute .. but nothing happen

Comment: can't you pass the data you need as paramaters to your controller?

Comment: i will assume that i will be able to pass it as parameter ... how can i carry the photo to the server ... and what data type ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload images with jQuery modal dialog sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080203/upload-images-with-jquery-modal-dialog-sample)